# Operaciones en diferentes cards con un array de objetos

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, ionic

Hola a todos me encuentro con un problema al momento de trabajar un array de objetos en diferentes cards que se crean dinamicamente a traves de NgFor de Angular.

A continuacion muestro imagenes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Data para crear estas cards.

[image: Array de objetos de las cards]

La cantidad recibida del input que se muestra ahí tiene que ser menor a la cantidad que tiene el producto en la card, si es menor manda una alerta y muestra la diferencia que hay entre cantidad recibida y cantidad solicitada.

Mi problema es como trabajar con cada array en cada una de las cards por separado, trato de trabajarlos con un for in pero siempre que le doy aceptar en cualquiera de los 2 me devuelve la operación de la ultima card.

Adjunto el código de la función.

```js
aceptar() {

    let cantidadSolicitada;
    let cantidadTotal;
    let precioUnitario;

    // console.log(this.cantidadSolicitada);
    // const date = new Date();
    const now = moment().format("YYYY MM DD");

    for (const [index, val] of this.conceptos.entries()) {

      console.log('index', index, '-value', val);
      cantidadSolicitada = val.Cantidad;
      cantidadTotal = val.Importe;
      precioUnitario = val.ValorUnitario;
      const cantidadR = this.cantidadRecibida;


      const diferencia = Number((cantidadSolicitada - cantidadR).toFixed(2));
      const monto = Number((diferencia * precioUnitario).toFixed(2));

      if (cantidadR < cantidadSolicitada) {
        Swal.fire({
          type: "error",
          title: "Existe diferencia entre la mercancía recibida y la facturada",
          text: "¿Desea guardar la información?",
          showCancelButton: true,
          confirmButtonText: "Aceptar"
        }).then(result => {
          if (result.value) {
            this.facturaRechazada = true;
            Swal.fire({
              position: "center",
              type: "error",
              title: `Existe una diferencia de ${diferencia.toFixed(2)}`,
              showConfirmButton: false,
              timer: 2000
            });
          }
        });
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logre resolverlo pasando el index del ngfor por la función y luego hacer una comparación con el index de mi for.

```js
aceptar(indexFactura) {

for (const [index, val] of this.conceptos.entries()) {
      if (index === indexFactura) {
      }

}
```

```html
<ion-card *ngFor="let concepto of conceptos; let i = index">
           <ion-button
                  expand="full"
                  (click)="aceptar( i )"
                  color="success"
                  class="ion-no-margin"
                >
<ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="checkmark"></ion-icon>
</ion-button>
```

Comment: Es la manera correcta de hacerlo, me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto tú mismo.

Comment: Muchas gracias Pablo estaba un poco bloqueado decidí venir aquí a pedir ayuda pero logre calmarme y logre pensar esta manera, saludos.

Comment: Muchas veces el hecho de escribir la pregunta te hace pensar con más claridad, es una especie de [Patito de goma](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9todo_de_depuraci%C3%B3n_del_patito_de_goma)

Comment: Vaya que si, no había escuchado de ese método pero vaya que me funciono jaja